# How to implement dynamic via_tuple reg in exactor?

Tags: elixir

I am starting genserver for every user, using their ID as name.

```
def start_link(id) do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, id, name: via_tuple(id))
  end

defp via_tuple(id) do
    {:via, :gproc, {:n, :l, {:id, id}}}
  end
```

Api then looks like:

```
def state(id) do
  GenServer.call(via_tuple(id), :state)
end

def handle_call(:state, _, state) do     
 {:reply, state, state}
end
```

Hope question makes sense, but is it possible to register process like this via exactor's export option? So entire api thing would end up something like:

```
defcall get(id), state: state, do: reply(state)
```

I see `ExActor.GenServer, export: {:via, :gproc, :calculator}` but can't get users ID to there.